# Local device not visible in Record & Run settings

Tags: appium, hp-uft, uft14

I'm trying to record a simple flow of an android app, However I don't see my local connected device to select, under Record and Run Settings. I have already installed Digital lab lite plugin.

device not in the list

[image]

Also I found this in device_connections.log

> [Android] device: result of rest query DPC is device owner? {"isActiveAdmin":false,"isDeviceOwner":false}